# I dont see the last version of a reusable workflow in sharepoint designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am using sharepoint 2013. My colleage has created a reusable workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013. I see something strange. I dont see the last version of this workflow in my SharePoint designer. I mis some loggin actions. The differance is I am using SPD on the APP server. My colleage has changed the workflow from he's local computer in SPD.

Is this some caching? He has saved and published he's workflow. And when I strart this workflow it is working fine.

Comment: Are you both using same site/farm?

Comment: yes, the same site collection. I found the solution. See it here below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empty this folder:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache

or 

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
```